# A variety is the moduli space of structure sheaves of points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, mirror-symmetry

In the last paragraph of the first page of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05894.pdf), it is mentioned that an $n$-dimensional Calabi-Yau manifold $X$ is the moduli space of structure sheaves of its points and I am not really sure what this exactly means. Is this trying to mention the functor-of-points viewpoint or is there some other result? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is nothing special to Calabi-Yau manifolds.  If $\check{X}$ is any complex manifold, we can say that $\check{X}$ parametrizes the structure sheaves of points of $\check{X}$ in the (tautological) sense that there is a bijection
\begin{align*}
\{\mathcal O_p:  p \in \check{X}\} \leftrightarrow \{p:  p \in \check{X}\} = \check{X}.
\end{align*}
If you want to be extra-formal, you can upgrade this to an isomorphism of functors of points.  Namely, for each morphism $f:  T \to \check{X}$, we can take its graph $\Gamma(f) \subset \check{X} \times T$; the structure sheaves of these graphs will parametrize the morphisms $f$.  (The special case $T = *$ recovers the earlier bijection.)

What does this give you in the context of the paper?  We're assuming that there is an equivalence of categories
$$
\mathcal{Fuk}(X) \cong D^b(\mathrm{Coh}(\check{X}))
$$
identifying certain features on each side with each other (cf. the table in the paper).  In particular, the sheaves $\mathcal O_p$ form a family of objects of the right-hand category, parametrized by $\check{X}$.  So there must be a corresponding family of objects of the left-hand category, also parametrized by $\check{X}$.  This is the family of Lagrangians mentioned in the following sentence of the paper.  Then one can identify the Floer cohomology groups of these objects with the Ext groups of the sheaves $\mathcal O_p$.

Comment: The subject is a Kahler manifold, not necessarily a variety. One can still talk about functor of points?

Comment: @AGlearner yes, thank you.  I admittedly don't know much about Kähler manifolds, but one can talk about functors of points in any category whatsoever--it's just a way of thinking about the Yoneda embedding.

Comment: Well, it is still true that a topological space is a moduli space of its points. For instance, given $X$ a topological space, $\mathrm{Hom}(-,X)$ defines a contravariant functor from $\mathrm{Top}$ to set. If you plug in the one point space, you see that Homs of a point to $X$ are the same as points in $X$, etc.